# VB .net get the client connection params of the socket on server side

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, synchronization, client-server

I want both the client and server to write and read resp. at a constant rate (which can be configured on the GUI of the client) to the buffer.

Say,

1. I am able to send from the client at 150 bytes per packet
2. Now, I should be able to read also at 150 bytes per packet on the server too

Since, both are connected through a socket, can we retrieve the socket params (set on the client size, like 150 here) from the server end, using the *tcpServer* object.

Or is it must to send an initial setup packet which tells about these client params and so accordingly the server can continue?

Comment: Whay protocol are you using?  TCP transfers byte streams, not packets, so you would need some protocol on top to exchange 'packets'.

Comment: I am using TCP only.. but for some bandwidth testing purposes over lan/wireless, I need to send data in small chunks to the other side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kinda usual to sort message sizes out at the application level.  You could indeed send a 'setup message' as the first data after a successful connect.  You should send this setup message in a form that will not be misunderstood due to endianness or the number of bytes received per read call.  Perhaps a fixed-size messge in ASCII, maybe five bytes:

'00150'

The server can then read five bytes only, convert to integer, save it in the server-client socket object so that the server always knows how many bytes to send and then issue a read call for that number of bytes.

Alternatively, you could use a simple protocol that embeds the size into each message, eg:

SOH
"0"
"0"
"1"
"5"
"0"
[150 bytes of data]
EOT

Rgds,
Martin